# Have a problem send my token value for deauthentication

Tags: loadrunner

I am not able to send my token value for logging out of the application. My request is as follows:

```
    web_submit_data("deauthenticate",
    "Action=https://some.com/deauthenticate",
    "Method=POST",
    "RecContentType=application/vnd.api+json",
    "Referer=https://some.com/logout",
    "Snapshot=t99.inf",
    "Mode=HTTP",
    ITEMDATA,
    "Name=token", "Value={sessionValue}", ENDITEM,
    LAST);
```

The {sessionValue} is previously correctly captured before logging into the system as:

```
   web_reg_save_param_json(
    "ParamName=sessionValue",
    "QueryString=$.access_token",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    "RequestUrl=https://some.com/authenticate",
    LAST);
```

When  I am passing the same {sessionValue} to the logout request I do not see the token value in the request body. The token value needs to be sent as a request body for the logout action(This is what I see in the replay snapshot). Any ideas on why the session value is being sent in the logout request.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that you have correctly captured the value and that you have a correlated element to populate?

Comment: In the output the see the {sessionValue} as "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjcmVkZW50aWFsX2lkIjo2MDI4NjYzNTgsImV4cCI6MTU3MTEwNDA2MH0.iDq21BeXIdY5jk-6AoM3Th7ZGLrD0q1jt5z-WDJcnD0"."  this is captured when the user is logged in.

Comment: Do you have snapshots on, and checking the request there?

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste the request and response snapshots (Raw mode, in order to include both header and body) for both recording and replay?